# R - List of combinations with outer() and expand.grid()

Tags: r

I have a list of prime numbers with I multiply using `outer()` and `upper.tri()` to get a unique set of numbers.

```
primes <- c(2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29)
m <- outer(primes, primes, "*")
unq <- m[which(upper.tri(m))]

> unq
6  10  15  14  21  35  22  33  55  77  26  39  65  91 143  34  51  85 119 187 221  38  57  95 133 209 247 323  46  69 115 161 253 299 391 437 58  87 145 203 319 377 493 551 667
```

Each of the original prime numbers represents a set of two numbers:

```
a2 <- c(1,1)
a3 <- c(1,2)
a5 <- c(2,2)
a7 <- c(1,3)
a11 <- c(1,4)
a13 <- c(2,3)
a17 <- c(2,4)
a19 <- c(3,3)
a23 <- c(3,4)
a29 <- c(4,4)
```

The combination of the two sets of two numbers produces 4 numbers

```
expand.grid(a2,a3)

1    1
1    1
1    2
1    2
```

So what I would like to do is have a kind of a list of lists, with each prime number having all 4 possible combinations.
I tried something like this, but I am missing some fundamentals here:

```
outer(a ,a , "expand.grid")
```

So the result would look something like this for the first prime:

```
   6 c(11, 11, 12, 12)
```

Comment: I'm not following this at all. What is the relationship between say `a7` and `c(1,3)`? Why are you generating combinations? Why are there only 4 possible combinations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand correctly, but I hope this helps:

```
#function to `outer`
fun <- function(x, y) 
{ 
 a1 <- get(paste0("a", x))
 a2 <- get(paste0("a", y))
 res <- apply(expand.grid(a1, a2), 1, paste, collapse = "")
 res2 <- paste(res, collapse = ";")

 return(res2)
}

#`outer` a vectorized `fun`
m2 <- outer(primes, primes, Vectorize(fun))
#select `upper.tri`
unq2 <- m2[upper.tri(m2)]

#combine to a list
myls <- lapply(as.list(unq2), function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, ";"))))
names(myls) <- unq

myls
#$`6`
#[1] 11 11 12 12

#$`10`
#[1] 12 12 12 12

#$`15`
#[1] 12 22 12 22

#$`14`
#[1] 11 11 13 13
#...
```